# Can you use Google Places WebService Api on Android instead of Google Places Api for Android?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I have an Android application which requires some features that are not available in the Google Places for Android Api. Can you legally use the Google Places Web Service Api on Android? My code is working fine with Webservice Api, I just need to know if it is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Places API Policies](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies) contains the following paragraph:

> ### Mobile Applications
>
> If developing a mobile application it is recommended that you provide a link to your Terms of Use and Privacy Policy on your applications download page in the relevant application store and in an application settings menu.

At this point it doesn't look like a web service is prohibited for Android.